# Phpmyadmin 403 forbidden, require granted all works, but specific ip does not

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I know this is a very common problem and there are many posts regarding this issue. But I was not able to find a solution to my problem:

I'm not able to access the `/phpmyadmin/` page of my site.

The only way I'm able to access `/phpmyadmin/` is to put require all granted in the `phpmyadmin.conf` file.

Almost every solution provides this answer to put require all granted in the config file but this is poor advice and can potentially harm your site because you basically give everyone access to phpmyadmin.

But I can't understand why giving access to all users works but my specific public IP (and other IP's) does not work. That basically means there is some other (IP) restriction going on somewhere.

Also adding different subnets did not work (like /16 /8).

Is there something I'm missing here?

To clarify:

This works:

```
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
 # Apache 2.4
 <RequireAny>
  Require ip 127.0.0.1
  Require ip ::1
  Require all granted
</RequireAny>
```

But this does not work:

```
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
         # Apache 2.4
         <RequireAny>
           Require ip 127.0.0.1
           Require ip ::1
           Require ip [my public ip]
         </RequireAny>
```

Comment: Can you show us your conf?

Comment: Have you tried something like `Require all denied Require ip 127.0.0.1` ? ... and is this on `XAMPP` using `httpd.xampp.conf` or some other Apache rollout?

Comment: Added the config in the main post. This is not XAMPP but a manual installation of apache and mariadb on CentOs. @cd001 Could you clarify why Require all denied would fix this problem? Just tried it but does not work.

Comment: @biggydeen - I thought you were trying to avoid `require all granted` so you'd generally set denied *first* then specify which IPs to allow - but since you've put it all in a `<RequireAny>` block it's not necessary. I'd assumed it was in something like `<VirtualHost> > <Directory>`